# Website Login GetElementById(...)

Tags: c#, youtube, getelementbyid

I am trying to log in into my youtube account by typing my credentials into two textBoxes.
I have also a button and a webbrowser. This is the [youtube login page](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=youtube&uilel=3&hl=en_US&passive=true&continue=http://www.youtube.com/signin?action_handle_signin=true&feature=sign_in_button&hl=en_US&next=%252Fresults%253Fsearch_query%253Dc%252523%252Byoutube%252Blogin%2526oq%253Dc%252523%252Byoutube%252Blogin%2526gs_l%253Dyoutube.3...30254.32728.0.33045.16.11.0.5.5.0.72.538.11.11.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.GUNH6NbA5ys&nomobiletemp=1) :

Code of the button :

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value",credentials[0]);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Passwd").SetAttribute("value", credentials[1]);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("submit");
```

So my problem now is that it does not click the sign in button. If I click start, it automatically types in my email and my password, but it does not click the login button.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try just calling in the click event using jQuery on the signIn button.

also, the method name is not submit, the name is signIn

Comment: Yep I just found it now too. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before but in a few more steps.

```
using mshtml;

    static private SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 Web_V1;
    Form1_Load ()
    {
        Web_V1 = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    }

    webBrowser1_DocumentComplete ()
    {
        HTMLDocument pass = new HTMLDocument(Web_V1.Document);
        HTMLInputElement passBox = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("Passwd", 0);
        passBox.value = "Password"; 
        HTMLInputElement logBox = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("Email", 0);
        logBox.value = "Email";
        HTMLInputElement submit = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("signIn", 0);
        submit.click();
    }
```

That's worked for me before.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InvokeMember("click")` for this

But if you face similar problems then check if some ajax function is still executing or not.

Even though the document load event gets fired if there are ajax calls still loading then you may not get the full Document till the ajax function gets completed.

For that you will need to wait till it gets loaded and then Invoke the member.
[Check this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread5134-ajax-page-load-using-web-browser-control.aspx) on how to wait till ajax loading gets complete.